# React & Mobx - invoking API calls best practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx-react

I'm very new to React / Mobx. I would like to incorporate best practices from the get-go. I've built out several different components with various data types and API calls.

One of the concerns I have is the way I've implemented the `useEffect` in my components. I have several components that render the same state store and make the same call to fetch the data from the same API. If I include these components in the same page, each component will invoke a call to the same API, essentially fetching the same data N number of times.

For example:

```js
const AlertsVisualization = ({ id }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        alertsStore.getAlertsForId(id);
    }, [id]);

    return (
        // render a visualization
    )
}

export default observer(AlertsVisualization)
```

```js
const AlertsList = ({ id }) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        alertsStore.getAlertsForId(id);
    }, [id]);

    return (
        // render a list
    )
}

export default observer(AlertsList)
```

In this example, I have two components that use the same state store but render it slightly different. If I include both of these components on the same page, it will invoke the `getAlertsForId(...)` twice, thus creating two separate calls for the same exact data.

So my question is, where should I be invoking the `getAlertsForId(...)` function?

Comment: The parent component where these exist should be fetching the data, then even if these are conditionally rendered they have the data right off the get-go. Seems like you just need the same data in two places while they exist in the same tree, perfect to just pass down through props.

Comment: @Perniferous Pass down through props or should the components tie directly into the state store? i.e., passing an ID (or some reference) where the data can be read from the store.

Comment: Either or would both work fine. This sounds like a direct parent->child sequence though and so I wouldn't access through the store. Simpler just to pass down.